# Автоматическая смена width JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

*Всем привет:)*

**Проблемная часть кода:**

```
 var posChange = function() {
         if ($(document).width() <= '340') {
             $('nav>ul>li>ul').css('position', 'inherit');
            $('nav').css('width','auto');
         } else {
             $('nav>ul>li>ul').css('position', 'absolute');
            $('nav').css('width','806px');


         }
     };
     $(window).on('load resize', posChange);
```

**В чем проблема:**

При установке этой функцией значения width в 806px ,размер перестает изменяться обратно при размере окна браузера в 304 px.
Собстно,даже если убрать часть функции,устанавливающую значение и прописать значение в css -> это все дело тоже не работает как надо.

**Задача и чего я всем этим хочу добиться:**

Есть менюшка.
Менюшка должна терять абсолютное позиционирование(точнее подсписок nav>ul>li>ul должен) при размере окна браузера ниже 340
(в будущем из переменной,но сейчас значения оно не имеет) и...так же должна терять любое настроенное значение поля width...(элемент nav должен)
Ну,а по возвращению в >340px под-список (nav>ul>li>ul) должен получить обратно абсолютное позиционирование ,а nav должен вернуть свою ширину...

Позиционирование меняет свойства как положено,проблема только с шириной.

Если есть какие то еще способы сделать тоже самое,буду рад о них услышать,в JQ пару дней...эксперементируем)

---

**Весь Html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css">
    <script src="nav.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Выпадающее меню1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Выпадающее меню2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Выпадающее меню3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Выпадающее меню4</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Выпадающее меню5</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Весь css:**

```
a {
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100px 100px;
}

nav {
    margin: auto;
}

nav ul {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav>ul>li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav>ul>li>ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    Color: #39b1a3;
    background: #303030;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0.05px #153c38;
    height: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 10px 25px #d1f1e1;
    Color: #256e68;
}

nav>ul>li>ul>li>a {
    background: #3b3b3b;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0.05px #153c38;
}
```

**Весь JS:**

```
 $(function() {
     var opac = $("nav>ul>li>a").css("opacity");

     //При наведении на любой из элементов меню\подменю все остальные not(this) становятся прозрачнее.
     $("nav>ul li a").hover(
         function() {
             $("nav>ul li a").not(this).stop().animate({
                 opacity: "0.85"
             }, 300);
         },

         function() {
             $("nav>ul li a").not(this).stop().animate({
                 opacity: opac
             }, 300);

         });

     //Все внутренние подсписки останавливают свою анимацию,пояляются\изчезают при наведении/
     $("nav>ul>li").hover(
         function() {
             $(this).children("ul").stop(false, true).fadeIn(200);
         },

         function() {
             $(this).children("ul").stop(false, true).fadeOut(1);

         });
     //Вычисляем размер окна браузера.
     //Если оно ниже нужного - убираем абсолютное позиционирование,убираем статический размер блоку nav.Под нужным на данный момент 340px.
     var posChange = function() {
         if ($(document).width() <= '340') {
             $('nav>ul>li>ul').css('position', 'inherit');
             $('nav').css('width', 'auto');
         } else {
             $('nav>ul>li>ul').css('position', 'absolute');
             $('nav').css('width', '806px');
         }
     };

     $(window).on('load resize', posChange);
 });
```

Comment: добавьте css и html код

Comment: Добавлено в конец поста :)

Comment: не очень понимаю, с чем связано использование js, а не media-query?

Comment: С полным не знанием midia-query, полагаю :)
Использую то,что известно или изучается в данный момент.

Comment: `if(width < 340) { ... } else if(width > 340) { ... }`

Comment: @HamSter, предложенная вами конструкция работает в точности так же,как и моя :) 
Проверено с изменениями:
    else if($(document).width() > '340'){
             $('nav>ul>li>ul').css('position', 'absolute');
             $('nav').css('width', '806px');
         }

Comment: Не очень понимаю, как может быть то что описано в задаче (одно в условии выполняется, а другое нет), но могу предположить, что замена $(document).width() <= '340' на $(window).width() <= 340 поможет

Comment: + 340 без кавычек + кстати да не document, a window.width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

обычно задаю еще и `else if` + ресайз `$(window).width()`:

```js
$(function() {
     var opac = $("nav>ul>li>a").css("opacity");

     //При наведении на любой из элементов меню\подменю все остальные not(this) становятся прозрачнее.
     $("nav>ul li a").hover(
         function() {
             $("nav>ul li a").not(this).stop().animate({
                 opacity: "0.85"
             }, 300);
         },

         function() {
             $("nav>ul li a").not(this).stop().animate({
                 opacity: opac
             }, 300);

         });

     //Все внутренние подсписки останавливают свою анимацию,пояляются\изчезают при наведении/
     $("nav>ul>li").hover(
         function() {
             $(this).children("ul").stop(false, true).fadeIn(200);
         },

         function() {
             $(this).children("ul").stop(false, true).fadeOut(1);

         });
     //Вычисляем размер окна браузера.
     //Если оно ниже нужного - убираем абсолютное позиционирование,убираем статический размер блоку nav.Под нужным на данный момент 340px.
     function posChange() {
         if ($(window).width() <= 340) {
             $('nav>ul>li>ul').css('position', 'inherit');
             $('nav').css('width', 'auto');
         } else if($(window).width() > 340){
             $('nav>ul>li>ul').css('position', 'absolute');
             $('nav').css('width', '806px');
         }
     };

    $(window).on('load resize', posChange);
 });
```

```css
a {
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100px 100px;
}

nav {
    margin: auto;
}

nav ul {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav>ul>li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav>ul>li>ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    Color: #39b1a3;
    background: #303030;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0.05px #153c38;
    height: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 10px 25px #d1f1e1;
    Color: #256e68;
}

nav>ul>li>ul>li>a {
    background: #3b3b3b;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0.05px #153c38;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

  
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Выпадающее меню1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Выпадающее меню2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Выпадающее меню3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Выпадающее меню4</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Выпадающее меню5</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Вложенность3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

хотя данный пример будет работать и без `else if` , просто с `else`

Comment: это же глупо ... if(width <= 340) else {} и if(width <= 340) else if(width > 340) {} - абсолютно одно и то же

Comment: Угу,в точности так сейчас код и выглядит(Если ничего кроме JQ не менялось),разве что с else,но в браузерах Gchrome и FF(обычном и Dev Edition,если это имеет значение) - функция применяется только в случае изменения размера окна браузера,но не при загрузке.
Нооо...здесь код работает как надо...странности...


Edit:психанул,копирнул все ради эксперимента,однако,при загрузке функция не срабатывает.

Comment: @RoseSevenyears, у меня все отлично и при загрузке работает

Comment: Как оказалось разница в работе разных версий библиотек.
в 2x - работает при загрузке, в 3х - нет.
Однако,на данный момент проблему можно считать решенной и,стало быть,этот ответ верным.

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из задачи логичнее использовать медиа квери, почему решили использовать js не знаю, может были на это причины, но на всякий случай напишу:

**CSS**

```
nav > ul > li > ul { position: absolute; }
nav { width: 806px; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 340px){
  nav > ul > li > ul { position: inherit; }
  nav { position: auto; }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ,но,хотелось бы на данном этапе ограничиться html,css,js+JQ :)
Использовать что-то,чего не знаю (хоть и интуитивно понятное) не хотелось бы :)

Comment: Ну вообще, это css (азы адаптивной верстки), но я понял к чему ты клонишь ))

Comment: прошу прощения,действительно, css(Видать,пора мне его подтянуть)....
Однако,в таком случае появляется еще одна деталь,я планирую использовать переменную вместо значений 340px и 806px в будущем,чего мне чистый css никак не простит,насколько мне,опять таки известно :)

Comment: Ну, тут да, зависит от задачи, если ты знаешь заранее "точки перелома" то лучше медиа квери, если эти точки должен просчитывать js, то я там под твоим постом откомментил свое предположение, попробуй, будем посмотреть)